# Submit PHP form in OpenSocial gadget

Tags: php, opensocial, igoogle

I'm trying to implement an [OpenSocial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSocial) gadget for [iGoogle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGoogle).
I'm writing my application in PHP and then "wrapping" it in an opensocial container using the XML gadget specification.

If I run my PHP in a stand-alone page it works fine, in an iGoogle container when I press the button on the form it says "The web page could not be found".

What am I doing wrong here? Is this the right way to go if I want to implement my gadget using PHP, is this even possible?

The XML gadget description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
    <ModulePrefs title="Register interest 29">
        <Require feature="opensocial-0.8"/>
        <Require feature="views" />
        <Preload href="http://opensocial-resources.googlecode.com/svn/samples/tutorial/tags/api-0.8/gifts.json" />
    </ModulePrefs>
    <Content type="html" href="http://myserver.com/OpenSocialSamples/test7.php">
    </Content>
</Module>
```

And I have the `test7.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Random DBpedia reader example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="test7.php" method=post">
            Search: <input type=text name="searchString"><br>
            <input type=submit value="Get data" >
        </form>

        <br><br>
        <h3> Data Test: </h3>
        <?php
            if ($_GET['searchString']) {
                echo $_GET['searchString'];
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the full path to `test7.php` in the form action.

Comment: Well spotted! Is this the right way to go if I want to implement my gadget using PHP, is this even possible?

Comment: Personally I would write a small javascript client and talk to my server over gadgets.io.makeRequest.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it works properly if use Content type="url" instead of "http"